# C++ wstring constructor

Tags: c++, wstring

How come this fails to compile:

```
std::wstring timeString();
if (sysTime->wHour < 10) timeString.append(L"hi");
```

But once I change the first line to be like this:

```
std::wstring timeString(L"some text");
```

It works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::wstring timeString();
```

This is a function declaration, not object declaration. Look it carefully : the function name is `timeString` which takes no argument, and returns `std::wstring`.

Just write:

```
std::wstring timeString;
```

That should be enough.

Only if you prefer C++11's *uniform initialization* syntax, you could avoid such accidental error:

```
std::wstring timeString { L"some text" };  //object!

std::wstring timeString { };  //object, not function declaration!
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well this works. But what makes that a function declaration, and not std::wstring timeString(L"hi")?

Comment: @Motig: Search for *"vexing parse in C++"* on this site, you will get lots of topics discussing this.

Comment: Thanks nawaz. (10 characters)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
std::wstring timeString();
```

with:

```
std::wstring timeString;
```